# Hardcoded TextView and Needed String?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm confused on why I need to have a String and not a hardcoded TextView. Eclipse tells me I need to use a String but I don't want to have multiple Strings in my `strings.xml` so I won't get confused. What should I do to get these error messages to go away?

Comment: It's good practice. Those things are just warnings, it does not affect compiling at all.

Comment: Well I've been developing for Android for quite awhile and have just been using AIDE on my device and then I finally get Eclipse and this is what happens

Comment: I know how to use Strings and I use them all the time, but using them too much is what gets annoying.

Comment: You should use strings if you want to sell your app in different countries; it makes internationalization far easier than the alternative.

Answer (score 2):

This does not affect compile time, but to get rid of the warnings, add this to your `View`s

```
 tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
```

Eg

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/large_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
```

Alternatively, you can open up the Lint window which provides more options, and a way to batch handle these warnings.

Go to:

> Window -> Show View -> Android -> Lint Warnings.

Then you will get a list of all the warnings and you can handle them accordingly.