# How do I open a new activity with a button click?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I recently started coding in Eclipse and I haven't done much yet so this is more or less my first app. I'm trying to make my school scheudele, it's simple: first activity shows 5 buttons, each button leading to a new activity (monday - friday).

How would I make so that when I click a certain button a new activity (let's say monday) would pop up?

I've seen hundreds of these questions already asked and answered on here but I just don't get it. It's useless to copy & paste code from here if I still don't get what's going on. I know I have to create a new intent and buttonlistener but I just don't get it what for and what to do then.

Could someone explain it to me as detailed as you can how exactly switching between activities using buttons work and how to actually do it?

I have:

- MainActivity.java
- Monday.java
- 5 buttons (button1-5)

So how would I code button1 to switch from MainActivity.java to Monday.java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by adding `android:onClick="onClick"` to each of your buttons' XML elements. This will make your buttons execute the `onClick` method whenever an onClick event is triggered on them.

Then in your `MainActivity` class add the following method:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
        // Monday
       Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Monday.class);
       startActivity(intent);
       break;
    case R.id.button2:
        // Tuesday
       Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Tuesday.class);
       startActivity(intent);
       break;
    // the rest of the buttons go here
    default: Log.e("YourTAG", "Default in onClick hit!");
        break;
    }
}
```

So every time there is an `onClick` event on any of your five buttons, the `onClick` method above will execute with the argument representing the `View` you just clicked on.

Details regarging intents and how they work [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#BuildIntent)

And as @Edward noted, don't forget to add your new activities in your *AndroidManifest.xml* file under the `application` element, such as:

```
<activity android:name=".Monday" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
```

Comment: Two precautions: you need to declare your **Monday** activity in your manifest; explicitly naming it in the intent is not enough. Second, be aware that the **android:onClick** property is new as of API 4. If you're trying to make your code work on an Android 1.5 system, it will silently fail.

Comment: Thank you so much! After hours and hours of failing I finally made it! And the most important thing --> I actually feel like I understand it. The only part of this code I still don't get is what the (View V)...why did you declare View and v...this is the only part I don't get. Thank you so much!

Comment: The `v` will represent the `View` (in your case one of the buttons) you clicked on. Why declare it like that? More details here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:onClick

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've got one more question that does not have to do anything with switching between activities though. For example when I create TextView on a random activity and I change android:text="" to something else than default, why does it say that I should use string resource? is that neccessary or can I work without string resources and simply just put my text between ""?

Comment: There are many reasons as to why you should use string resources, one example: Let's say you have a button with the text "continue" and you have that button on multiple activities. If you then decide you want to change the text "continue" to "proceed", you'd have to change this in every XML file that contains the button. With string resources, you'd change it once in the strings.xml file and every button referring to this string would be updated. A bit of a silly example, but you get the point. It's not mandatory, but recommended.

Comment: Thanks, I get why it is useful now, but how do I bypass this? I am making a scheudele, which means I'd have to make atleast 35 string resources...every activity about 7-8 different texts and 5 activities. It's too time consuming making a string resource. Do i have to do something special to bypass making a string resource? Because a yellow ! appears next to the code if I don't make a string resource and it won't let me compile.

Comment: I've never had to do anything to bypass this. Strange that it doesn't compile. This person has a similar issue and may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14206522/hardcoded-textview-and-needed-string.

Answer (score 0):

what you should do is to create an `Intent` that will fire your `Activity` you do that by this code:

```
startActivity(new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, Monday.class));
```

You will have to fire a different `Intent` on each button that will create the appropriate `Activity`. 
Of course don't forget to declare your `Activity`s in your manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Lets say you have following button in your layout file:-

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/my_btn"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="22dp"
    android:onClick="goToMonday"  // function name which will be in MainActivity.java
/>
```

Now in your MainActivity.java:-

```
public void goToMonday(View v){
    Intent monday_intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Monday.class);

    MainActivity.this.startActivity(monday_intent);
}
```

This is the way to change activities.